# Getting undefined when trying to use a variable in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get all the values that is part of an object. What I'm struggling to do is use a variable filter for the part of the object I want.

So I have

```
getCategoryData(slug){
    console.log(this.categories.products.slug);
}
```

I end up with an undefined in my console.
`slug` in `this.categories.products.slug` is the variable I would like to use.

Comment: How is your variable actually constructed? You aren't trying to get it from array didn't u?

Comment: please provide more context, but i'm thinking you are calling the function somewhere before `this.categories` gets defined

Comment: @NizarZizoune - yes i'm calling a function somewhere else that is passing the slug over

Comment: Just check where does `this.categories` gets defined and make sure the call for your function `getCategoryData` is after it

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need

```
getCategoryData(slug){
    console.log(this.categories.products[slug]); // change added
}
```